# spark works too slow on dataframe generated by mongodb spark connector

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I used mongodb spark connector generated a dataframe from mongodb

```
val df1 = df.filter(df("dev.app").isNotNull).select("dev.app").limit(100)
```

It's a big collection, so I limit the row to 100.

when I use

> df1.show()

it works fast.

But when I use

```
df1.count
```

to see the fist row of df1

the result is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7N3G.png)

it is too slow.

Can anybody give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to tweak spark.sql.shuffle.partitions configuration. you may very small data but you are creating too many partitions by default it is 200 
[see this for info](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/sql-programming-guide.html)